# Calculating Lie derivative using definition

Tags: differential-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^4$, I was trying to calculate the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X w$ for $X=-x_1\partial_0+x_0\partial_1-x_3\partial_2+x_2\partial_3$ and $w=-x_2d_0+x_3d_1+ x_0d_2 -x_1d_3$ using the definition
$$
\mathcal{L}_Xw(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(\phi^X_t)^*(w(\phi^X_t(x)))-w(x)}{t},
$$
but I am having trouble to calculate the pullback explicitly. I already got the result using Cartan's formula, just want to work it out using the definition as an example.

Comment: Were you able to compute the flow of $X$? After that, the computation should be straightforward; just use the definition of the pullback: $$f^*\omega(V) = \omega(df(V)). $$

Comment: The problem is I don't necessarily have a V here, but need to calculate the explicit formula for $f^*w$.

Comment: You know that $f^*\omega = f_i dx^i$ for some smooth functions $f_i$. You can compute this functions by observing that $$f_i = f^*\omega(\partial_i). $$ After this, you have a concrete expression for $f^* \omega$.

Comment: I see what you mean! Just an extra comment, is it true that when $f^* w$ is no longer a 1-form but a $k$-form for some larger $k$, this method will not be handy any more?

Comment: If $\omega$ is a $k$-form, then you have to do more computations, but it is still a viable approach.